# Merge branches locally

Tags: mercurial, merge

I have a repository called 'Myproject' and within that we have a branch "MyProject-new changes"

I have cloned the "MyProject" repository in my local machine as 
c:/MyProject

and similarly cloned "MyProject-new changes" as 
c:/MyProject-new changes"

Both the repositories have the latest changes after pull and merge.

Now, I need the changes from "MyProject-new changes"(branch) changes merged into "MyProject" locally.

Once I merge, I don't want to commit these changes..I will revert back the changes as the branch changes are being worked. I just want to integrate the new changes and see the results for time being.

Please let me know the following

1. How do I merge locally the code from "MyProhect-new changes" to "Myproject"
2. How do I revert back MyProject once I tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need a test site where you can test merge.  Usually people create separate clone for experiments.  This gives you easy way to revert changes — just delete experimental clone.  So lets start from making another clone of MyProject and update on the latest commit in branch `default`.

Suppose revision 25 is the latest revision in branch `default`.  You can update on it with command `hg up -r 25`.

Suppose revision 37 is the latest revision in `MyProject-new changes`.  You can merge latest changes from `MyProject-new changes` into branch `default` with command `hg merge -r 37`.  After that you'll have merge result in your working directory.

Since you work in the separate clone you can commit without doubt.  Commit with `hg ci -m 'merge with new changes'` and test the result.  When you finished your tests you can simply delete experimental clone.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make a complete clone of your repository, merge and test to your heart's content, and throw out the repository when you're done. @Kirill explains how to do that.

But why do that? Maybe you'll come across problems, or small merge conflicts, that you'll fix in the clone. It will be a pity to throw away this work-- you'll probably need it in the future. You could simply keep the clone around, of course, but I suggest reconsidering your premise: **Why don't you want to merge the two branches?**

You have a main branch (`default`) and a feature branch `new-changes`, and you want to safely see how they work together. Here's two ways you can do this without cloning the repository:

1. To keep the `default` branch safe, simply merge from default *into* new-changes:

   ```
   hg update new-changes  # switch to the branch
   hg merge -r default
   ```

   You can now test new-changes and fix any problems. This is a very common workflow: Changes to `default` are incorporated into long-running branches to keep them from drifting too far apart. When you're eventually ready to unify the two lines of development, merge `new-changes` into the default line and everything will work correctly.
2. If you want to keep both branches pure for the time being, you can create a *new* branch `testing` and merge both existing branches into it. You can keep it around and eventually merge it into `default`, or close it if `new-changes` turns out to be a failed experiment. (Detail: If `testing` is rooted at the head of one of the branches, there'll be "nothing to merge" from that branch. You'll only need to merge the other one.)

If you don't want to risk messing up your main repo, you can of course clone it and try one of the above approaches on the clone. Once you're satisfied that it worked correctly, push everything back to the main repo.

Comment: I think the 1st option looks good..I made a mistake of merging new-changes into default and my default is screwed.The good thing is I have not committed it yet...How do I revert back to the default branch? ALso what do you mean by revision number? Im sure its not changesets id?, then how do I get it?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking me. If you started to merge, changed your mind and now you're sitting in a mess of files, use `hg update --clean .` (See `hg help merge`). For the rest, I think you meant to ask at the other answer? Anyway you can identify a revision either by id or by number. Take a good look at the output of `hg log`.